# Java update and delete function is giving me 'java.lang.IllegalStateException'

Tags: java, android

I am doing my android project and I am using an external API to connect it with the database. I have done the create and view by id. But when it comes to update and deleteI am getting error as `E/Failure message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $`. But I am getting the success message and the the error.

[image: Success message and error]

When I delete I am getting this error but when I re build the app the data is deleted. But the update is not working.

This is my external API

```
//Update fuel details
@PUT("/api/fuel/{id}")
Call<Fuel> updateFuel(@Path("id") int id,@Body Fuel fuel);

//Delete fuel details
@DELETE("/api/fuel/{id}")
Call<Fuel> deleteFuel(@Path("id") int id);
```

And this is my java class for the update and delete. I have tried for 2 days and still couldn't find a solution for this. Please give me some support. Thank You.

```
public class ShedFuelUpdateFormActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText fuelType, arrivalTime, arrivalAmount, availableAmount, finishTime;
Button deleteButton, updateButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shed_fuel_update_form_screen);

    fuelType = findViewById(R.id.fuelType );
    arrivalTime = findViewById(R.id.arrivalTime );
    arrivalAmount = findViewById(R.id.arrivalAmount );
    availableAmount = findViewById(R.id.availableAmount );
    finishTime = findViewById(R.id.finishTime );

    deleteButton = findViewById(R.id.deleteButton );
    updateButton = findViewById(R.id.updateButton );

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int fuelId = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("fuelId"));

    //Get fuel by id
    new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getFuel(fuelId);
        }
    }, 1000);

    //Call delete function
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteFuel(fuelId);

        }
    });

    //Call update function
    updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveFuel(fuelId, updateFuel());


        }
    });
}

//Get fuel by id details
public void getFuel(int id){
    Call<Fuel> getFuelCall = ApiClient.getFuelServices().getFuelById(id);
    getFuelCall.enqueue(new Callback<Fuel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Fuel> call, Response<Fuel> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                String fuelTypeData = response.body().getFuelType();
                String arrivalTimeData = response.body().getFuelArivalTime();
                String arrivalAmountData = String.valueOf(response.body().getArivalAmount());
                String availableAmountData = String.valueOf(response.body().getCurrentAvailableAmount());
                String finishTimeData = response.body().getFuelFinishedTime();

                fuelType.setText(fuelTypeData);
                arrivalTime.setText(arrivalTimeData);
                arrivalAmount.setText(arrivalAmountData);
                availableAmount.setText(availableAmountData);
                finishTime.setText(finishTimeData);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Fuel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Failure message",t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}

//Delete fuel details
public void deleteFuel(int id){
    Call<Fuel> deleteFuelCall = ApiClient.getFuelServices().deleteFuel(id);
    deleteFuelCall.enqueue(new Callback<Fuel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Fuel> call, Response<Fuel> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(ShedFuelUpdateFormActivity.this, "Fuel deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String shedId = intent.getStringExtra("shedId");
                Intent i = new Intent(ShedFuelUpdateFormActivity.this, ShedOwnerHomeActivity.class).putExtra("shedId",shedId);;
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(ShedFuelUpdateFormActivity.this, "Failed to delete fuel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Fuel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Failure message",t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}

//Update fuel
public Fuel updateFuel(){
    Fuel fuel = new Fuel();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int shedId = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("shedId"));
    fuel.setShedId(shedId);
    fuel.setFuelType(fuelType.getText().toString());
    fuel.setFuelArivalTime(arrivalTime.getText().toString());
    fuel.setArivalAmount(Integer.parseInt(arrivalAmount.getText().toString()));
    fuel.setCurrentAvailableAmount(Integer.parseInt(availableAmount.getText().toString()));
    fuel.setFuelFinishedTime(finishTime.getText().toString());

    return fuel;
}

//Save updated fuel
public void saveFuel (int id, Fuel fuel){
    Call<Fuel> createFuelCall = ApiClient.getFuelServices().updateFuel(id, fuel);
    createFuelCall.enqueue(new Callback<Fuel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Fuel> call, Response<Fuel> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(ShedFuelUpdateFormActivity.this, "Fuel details updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String shedId = intent.getStringExtra("shedId");
                Intent i = new Intent(ShedFuelUpdateFormActivity.this, ShedOwnerHomeActivity.class).putExtra("shedId",shedId);;
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(ShedFuelUpdateFormActivity.this, "Failed to update fuel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Fuel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Failure message",t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}